# How do I omit a package from being included in my yarn.lock file?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, npm-shrinkwrap

So in my package.json I have a bunch of npm libs, and one private repo being pulled in from a git ssh url which needs to always be the latest build. The yarn.lock adds the git sha and yarn upgrade etc won't grab the newest one.

Basically, given this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "some-package"        : "^0.x.x",
  "some-other-package"  : "*",
  "my-private-git-repo" : "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/me/myrepo.git",
  "lastlibrary"         : "^4.0.3"
},
```

I want yarn.lock or npm shrinkwrap to ignore `my-private-git-repo`

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue, have any other supported solutions become available?

Comment: Not that I know of, but the perl solution below is a simple one-liner and worked pretty nicely for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I managed to pull this off by using Perl to remove the cache entry from the file itself.

Given my package.json has this :

`"postinstall": "bash ./scripts/after_install.sh",`

My `after_install.sh` now has this :

`perl -0777 -i -pe 's/(?s)"myrepo.*?\n\n//s' ./yarn.lock`