# How to force Yarn to ignore yarn.lock and always install latest version?

Tags: yarnpkg

In my `package.json` file I have a dependency which I want to be always the latest version, no matter what's in `yarn.lock` or `yarn cache`, without having to run `yarn update` or something similar each time the package changes.

What I've tried

- `"my-package": "latest"` - doesn't work. Yarn ignores `latest`, the entry in `yarn.lock` seems to overrule
- `"my-package": "*"` - same here
- Removing `my-package` from `yarn-lock` in a post-install hook, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43923327/2710714), didn't work for me and feels very hacky.

I just want something in `package.json` which says: *"Dear Yarn, if you encounter this, please ignore your `yarn.lock` and always install the latest version of this package."*

Preferable, that should even be the case when running `yarn` with `--frozen-lockfile`.

Comment: I don't think Yarn will do that, as it means you no longer have a reproducible dependency tree. You'd have to exclude the lockfile from tracking, and therefore not use `--frozen-lockfile` at all, to get the latest versions on installation.

Comment: You can completely opt out of lockfile by setting `--install.no-lockfile true` in your `.yarnrc` (might be different for yarn berry). But I don't think there is any way to selectively opt out that behavior. You should run something like dependabot or renovate in your CI pipeline to keep your deps fresh.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you mean by "exclude the lockfile from tracking"? Even without `--frozen-lockfile` yarn does not install the latest version.

Comment: I mean delete it and put it in e.g. `.gitignore` so it's not part of your project's history. That way when when the repo's checked out somewhere and the install runs it'll pull the latest versions matching the semver specs in the direct dependencies. Then you always run with [`--no-lockfile`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-no-lockfile).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem on my project when update some dependencies, solution that I found was use a resolution in package.json... But if your problem is by a peerDependecy that may not work, in yarn original doc [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4vd2.png)
I've just clean my yarn cache and remove yarn.lock on pipe!

I'm waiting for a bugfix and looking for new solutions.